# Sentry Upload Fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, crash, apk, sentry

I'm new to sentry. I have a react native mobile application from react native version 0.59. I have set up sentry for the mobile app as per this guide.
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/

When I ran the react native bundle command and try to create an android build using android studio following error comes. I searched in google and couldn't find a proper answer for my question. Does anyone know how to fix this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you execute the `sentry-wizard` command and did it work? if yes, then please, export the system env. `SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL` as mentioned in the error message and paste us the full log so we could have a look into it.